# Добавить смайлики в textarea на blogger blogspot через javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть блог на blogspot. Установил в комментариях смайлики и чтобы не плодить много описаний как использовать их... хочу реализовать публикацию по клику. Нажал, появился код в текстовом поле...
Проблема в том, что само текстовое поле в iframe. И всё, что мог найти в инете, не подошло.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `iframe` от вашего домена?

Comment: Вы не можете сделать это , потому что это будет межсайтовый сценарий, который запрещен по соображениям безопасности. Вы можете использовать прокси-сервер, подавать HTML в iframe через свой собственный сайт, чтобы он больше не был межсайтовым с точки зрения браузера.

Comment: нет фрейм блоггеровский...
@Oleksii Zelenko спасибо, значит не буду дальше замарачиваться... повешу на смайлики alert и там код. думаю кому надо те поймут...)))